# Checking version of OpenCV (cv)

Tags: python, opencv, python-import, importerror

I was checking the version of OpenCV installed previously in a system.
I tried to check using

```
from cv2 import __version__
```

Its gave me the following error

> No module named cv2

When I tried `import cv`, it's not giving me error. Is there a way to know the version?

Answer (score 25):

Open a python interpreter (simply type *python* in your terminal). 
Now, you should import **cv2** and then check the special variable **version**.
Like this:

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

For more details, check this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/08/10/checking-your-opencv-version-using-python/)

Answer (score 6):

`__version__` is a variable and a property of the package, not something you can import. The general way to do this (from script or interpreter, Python 2 or Python 3):

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

You can check the version number of any Python package this way using the `__version__` string. Also note that if you want to know what other special `__variables__` are available, you can use the `dir()` function on your module:

```
import cv2
print(dir(cv2))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an old setup without a `cv2.__version__` variable (egg file was used to install opencv 2.4.2 for python 2.7.6 under windows 10; just returned `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'`)
This worked for all setups:

```
opencv_version = cv2.__version__ if hasattr(cv2, '__version__') else cv2.__file__.replace('\\','').replace('/','').split("cv2-")[-1].split("-")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

def print_hi(version):
print(f'Cv2 version is : {version}')

if **name** == '**main**':
import cv2
print_hi(cv2.**version**)